# A Kotlin function with single lambda expression as body

Tags: kotlin, syntax

What is the difference between runMyRunnable and runMyRunnable1 below?

```
fun runMyRunnable(runnable: () -> Unit) { runnable() } 

fun runMyRunnable1(runnable: () -> Unit) = { runnable() }

// Prints "Hello world"
runMyRunnable { println("Hello world") }


// Why it prints nothing ??
runMyRunnable1 { println("Hello world) }

// Why it Prints "Hello world" ??
runMyRunnable1 { println("Hello world") } ()
```

Comment: Notice `=` sign in `runMyRunnable1`. It means that the function returns value `{ runnable() }`. I.e. it does nothing except of you returning this value (this lambda expression). By doing `runMyRunnable1 {...} ()` you 1) return this lambda with `runMyRunnable1 {...}` 2) call this lambda with `()`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, this was helpful.

Comment: (and to run the runnable you could write `= runnable()` but it's less idiomatic than your first `runMyRunnable`.)

Answer (score 2):

An `=` after a function declaration instead of an opening brace `{` is shorthand for returning something immediately, without even having to declare the return type. So your function `runMyRunnable1` without this shortcut is the equivalent of

```
fun runMyRunnable1(runnable: () -> Unit): () -> Unit {
    return { runnable() } 
}
```

Since you put braces right after the `=`, the braces are defining a lambda function.

Your last line is calling the function and then the `()` at the end is calling the returned function, your lambda.